# Scala creating an instance of type alias

Tags: scala

I am wondering how to create an instance of type alias. More specifically this:

```
type Graph = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Statement, Statement]
```

I tried this but I get a type error saying `Map[Statement, Statement]` is not equivalent to `Graph`:

```
val graph: Graph = Map[Statement, Statement]().asInstanceOf[Graph]
```

Is this (i.e. creating a type alias) anti-pattern in Scala?

Comment: I can't reproduce with simple types in Scala. Is it possible you're accidentally using `scala.collection.immutable.Map` in the second snippet?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo oops, yes. I am sorry :)

Comment: Honestly, it's a common mistake (mutable vs immutable collections of the same name). I'm glad there's a question on here now so others can clear it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Map[?,?]` is always immutable except when an `import` might shadow it.

This works:

```
val graph: Graph = collection.mutable.Map[Statement, Statement]()
```